# How to check if request type is ajax in flask

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

Is there a simple way in flask to check if the request is ajax from view? Just like in django, its as easy as `request.is_ajax()` but I cant find anything like that for flask, i checked the docs but couldnt find it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Request.is_xhr):

```
request.is_xhr
```

**Notice:** This solution is deprecated and not viable anymore.